# How to distribute objects inside a shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, alignment, distribute

I have thousands of objects I want to distribute them inside a square shape with a same spacing.

I tried distribute object panel but... I think I have to align line by line which is tiring method.

What is the easiest way to do that?
[image]

What am looking for :

[image]

Comment: Is it the same image or multiple ones?

Comment: not same images

Comment: I think you'll need some advanced scripts.

Comment: @Vikas a for loop inside a for loop is hardly advanced.

Comment: @joojaa I think it's relative then. I never tried scripts so simplest thing can look difficult :P

Answer (score -1):

Space Fill by Astute Graphics.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  We are typically looking for long and detailed answers here, not just a single line.  Can you please edit your answer and explain how this can solve the OPs problem. Thanks.